# read_csv seperator is creating extraneous null columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following .txt file that I want to read into a Pandas dataframe:

```
#Date                     run               angle                NAME        
#-----                  _______            ________             _______    
2023-02-15 10:00:00      120716            -1.75493           4.5x10-4 Al 40um
2023-02-15 10:38:48      120716            -1.75493           JD70-103 50um 0/90 deg
2023-02-15 18:25:41      120723            -0.658             JD70-103 50um 45/135 deg
```

I am trying to read the .txt file using a regex separator that matches any number of whitespaces, unless preceded by a date ("\d\d:\d\d:\d\d"), "Al", "\d\dum", "deg", or something that looks like "[0-999]/[0-999]":

`df = pd.read_csv("file.txt", engine='python', sep='\s+(?!\d\d:\d\d:\d\d|Al|\d\dum|deg|((\d|\d\d|\d\d\d)\/(\d|\d\d|\d\d\d)))')`

For some reason, this is creating a dataframe that inserts three columns of NaN values in between each of my desired columns:

```
                  Date  NaN  None.1  None.2      run   None.3     None.4     None.5        angle ...
0  2023-02-15 10:00:00  NaN     NaN     NaN   120716      NaN        NaN        NaN     -1.75493 ...
1  2023-02-15 10:38:48  NaN     NaN     NaN   120716      NaN        NaN        NaN     -1.75493 ...
2  2023-02-15 18:25:41  NaN     NaN     NaN   120723      NaN        NaN        NaN     -0.658 ...
```

Any idea why this is happening? My best guess is that the seperator is separating multiple whitespaces in a row, but that is not the behavior I would expect from the regex I mentioned above.

Comment: don't you think it would be helpful to provide an example of the actual data?

Comment: A snippet of the data is included in the first code block.

Comment: That isn't very clear because you called it a "Pandas dataframe". So that us actually a snippet of the text file? Note, that is not a CSV. You are probably better off simply parsing it by hand and transforming it into an actual csv

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misspoke. That is the text file that I want to read into a dataframe. Thanks for pointing that out. I will edit my post.

Comment: Have you considered `pd.read_fwf()`? It looks like the field sizes are consistent.

Comment: So, for example, `for line in f: print(re.split(r'\s{3,}', line.strip()))` takes you most of the way there. I would just use that to create an actual CSV.

Comment: @Barmar that's a good thing to try out as well, it can probably infer the spec too (which it will try by default if you don't pass one specifically)

Comment: I have not tried read_fwf(). If I understand correctly, each entry in the column needs the same number of characters, which is not the case with this dataset

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. Won't this method be slower than read_csv though? The dataset I have is millions of lines long and I would like the most efficient method possible.

Comment: @bigboy1001 it doesn't need each entry to be the same number of characters, the actual function triees to infer a spec based on some number of rows, and it works pretty well actually

Comment: @bigboy1001 no, not really. it won't be slower. you are using the Python engine, it is basically going to do that underneath the hood. In any case, you only need to do it once (ideally, you should *fix* whatever is giving you this text file to provide an actual csv, or even better (if you care about performance) something like parquet). I would parse it manually. I would save whatever dataframe out create out of this as parquet if you care about performance. then load it from that moving forward

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. Although I am still confused as to why read_csv() is giving me the behavior that it is.

Comment: Looking into this more closely, I think it's because you are using capturing groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I **highly** suggest you fix your text file into an actual CSV, otherwise, reading it will be slow with `pandas` because you won't be able to use the arrow or C engines. Ideally, you would just read a parquet file. That would be fast.

The reason the regex you provide isn't working is because you are using capturing groups, you should use non-capturing groups. So:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, engine='python', sep=r'\s+(?!\d\d:\d\d:\d\d|Al|\d\dum|deg|(?:(?:\d|\d\d|\d\d\d)\/(?:\d|\d\d|\d\d\d)))')
```

worked for me on the example snippet you provided.

But I really cannot emphasize enough that you should fix this text file. Using a regex separator is a hack. Note, without cleaning up the text file, it parses, but everytthing is parsed as `dtype=object` which you definetly don't want. For preformance, you should create a parquet file, and read it with `pandas.read_parquet` (and since you care about performance sure you have `pyarrow` installed and use `dtype_backend='pyarrow'`)

Comment: Thank you so much for this comprehensive response.